# XSL recursive traverse based on variable

Tags: xslt

I'm trying to get my head around XSL recursion. I need to build an HTML table based on an XML using XSLT with cell tags where the position is mapped to a string attribute called name formatted like "row.column".

I'm trying to recursively start from the last cell and count back to the first cell ( 0.0 ) and start building the table. The reason for this is that some cells may span several cell positions. So for use in HTML I cannot just process the cells in a for-each loop. The last cell is identified by the table attributes; BodyRowCount and ColumnCount.

The XML looks like this

```html
<Table HeaderRowCount="0" FooterRowCount="0" BodyRowCount="4" ColumnCount="2" >
 <Cell Self="ucd8iceei0" Name="0:0" RowSpan="1" ColumnSpan="1">
  <Content>1</Content>
 </Cell>
 <Cell Self="ucd8iceei1" Name="1:0" RowSpan="1" ColumnSpan="1">
  <Content>2</Content>
 </Cell>
 <Cell Self="ucd8iceei2" Name="2:0" RowSpan="1" ColumnSpan="2>
  <Content>3</Content>
 </Cell>
 <Cell Self="ucd8iceei3" Name="3:0" RowSpan="1" ColumnSpan="1">
  <Content>4</Content>
 </Cell>
 <Cell Self="ucd8iceei4" Name="0:1" RowSpan="1" ColumnSpan="1">
  <Content>5</Content>
 </Cell>
 <Cell Self="ucd8iceei6" Name="2:1" RowSpan="1" ColumnSpan="1">
  <Content>7</Content>
 </Cell>
 <Cell Self="ucd8iceei7" Name="3:1" RowSpan="1" ColumnSpan="1">
  <Content>8</Content>
 </Cell>
</Table>
```

The result should be like this

```html
<Table>
 <tr> 
  <td>1</td>  <td>5</td> 
 </tr>
 <tr> 
  <td> colspan="2">2</td>
 </tr>
 <tr> 
  <td>3</td> <td>7</td> 
 </tr>
 <tr> 
  <td>4</td>  <td>8</td> 
 </tr>
</Table>
```

The XLS in pseudo format below. I tried to pass the arguments to start in this case at Cell with name 4.2 but that seems to be illigal to pass an argument based on the attributes, but surely this must be possible?

```html
<xsl:template match="Table">  
 <table>
  <xsl:apply-templates select="Cell[@Name = concat(@BodyRowCount,':',ColumnCount)']"/>
 </table>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template name="Cell[@name='0.0">
Found first cell, start first row in table
<tr><td colspan=<xsl:value-of select=(concat(3&quot,@ColumnSpan,3&quot))   rowspan=<xsl:value-of select=(concat(3&quot,@rowSpan,3&quot))> Row content here  </td></tr>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template name="Cell[@name='0.*">
 Call template with 'ROW-1, COLUMN back to max
 <xsl:apply-templates select="Cell[@Name = 'ROW-1:MAXCOLUMN']"> 
  new row goes here
  <tr><td colspan=<xsl:value-of select=(concat(3&quot,@ColumnSpan,3&quot))   rowspan=<xsl:value-of select=(concat(3&quot,@rowSpan,3&quot))> Row content here  </td></tr>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template name="Cell[@name='*.*">
 Call template with one column before
 <xsl:apply-templates select="Cell[@Name = SAME ROW:COLUMN-1']"> 
 <td colspan=<xsl:value-of select=(concat(3&quot,@ColumnSpan,3&quot))   rowspan=<xsl:value-of select=(concat(3&quot,@rowSpan,3&quot))> Row content here  </td>
</xsl:template>
```

I looking for some help on how to start up the recursive loop in 4.2 go back to 0.0, build the table by traversing all the positions and inserting the cell value if one exist ?

Comment: Are you using XSLT 1.0 or XSLT 2.0?

Comment: Hi I use V2, but if i change to V1 then the example provided by Andreas works without errors. So it seems that the versions behave differently.

Comment: If you use XSLT 2.0, then you can use the built-in grouping feature. -- Can you explain what determines the colspan? In your example, each cell already has RowSpan and ColumnSpan atributes - but your output has different values. Why is that?

Comment: Hi Well the spans are determined by the attributes as you mention, The output looks like I made a copy/paste error. Ill google up on the group feature.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need recursion for this. The xslt (1.0) way to do it could look like:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:key name="rows" match="Cell" use="substring(@Name,1,1)"/>
    <xsl:template match="Table">
        <table border="1">
            <xsl:apply-templates select="Cell[generate-id() = generate-id(key('rows',substring(@Name,1,1)))]" mode="row">
                <xsl:sort select="@Name"/>
            </xsl:apply-templates>
        </table>
    </xsl:template>
    <xsl:template match="Cell" mode="row">
        <xsl:variable name="row" select="substring(@Name,1,1)"/>
        <tr>
            <td>
                <xsl:if test="not(following-sibling::Cell[substring(@Name,1,1) = $row])">
                    <xsl:attribute name="colspan">2</xsl:attribute>
                </xsl:if>
                <xsl:value-of select="."/>
            </td>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="following-sibling::Cell[substring(@Name,1,1) = $row]" mode="secondcell"/>
        </tr>
    </xsl:template>
    <xsl:template match="Cell" mode="secondcell">
        <td>
            <xsl:value-of select="."/>
        </td>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

How is it done?
- Building a key on the rows information (first character of Name attribute)
- Apply the template for the rows on the found Cells
- Save first character of Name attribute in variable
- Check if following sibling with same first character exists
  - if not, add colspan (no need for information from XML, but could be used)
  - if so, apply template for second cell

Instead of <xsl:value-of select="."/> you can use <xsl:apply-templates/>. Thats not so obvious for beginners but more straight xslt. Purists will demand on it.

Edit @Christian: The key uses the first character of the attribute "name", so it returns  one "cell" element for each first character found. This is one for each row, so you can figure out the rows without having this information explicit in the xml tree. Additional cells in the row are detected, if there are following cells with the same first character.

Edit @Christian: The xslt 2.0 solution is ever shorter and doesn't need a key:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:fn="http://www.w3.org/2005/xpath-functions">
    <xsl:template match="Table">
        <table border="1">
            <xsl:for-each-group select="Cell" group-by="substring(@Name,1,1)">
                <tr>
                    <xsl:for-each select="current-group()">
                        <td>
                            <xsl:if test="count(current-group())=1">
                                <xsl:attribute name="colspan">2</xsl:attribute>
                            </xsl:if>
                            <xsl:value-of select="."/>
                        </td>
                    </xsl:for-each>
                </tr>
            </xsl:for-each-group>
        </table>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: Hi thanks. Thats quite a different approach. I have to read up on the 'key' expression. But for now it seems that it expects the line : <xsl:apply-templates select="Cell[generate-id() = generate-id(key('rows',substring(@Name,1,1)))]" mode="row"> is only allowed to  return max one key and it returns 2 or more as more cells begins with the same rownumber ?

Comment: @Christian: I added a xslt 2.0 solution without key

Comment: This doesn't look right. You assume that there are two columns; this could change. Also, `substring(@Name,1,1)` assumes less than 10 rows - this could change, too.

Comment: @michael.hor: Of course I stick at the question and the provided code. It would be much better to separate the row information into an own attribute. If not, you could use substring-before instead of substring and counting characters. At first I try to keep it simple.

Comment: Hi The answer is correct by Andreas (using XLST 1.0) but yes as Michael points out i can expect to get any number of row and coloums. Allthough I do have an idea on how to adapt the solution for that. The solution for XLST 2 by works as well. Thanks a lot.